# Is there a way to convert swagger json file into Pact contract file?

Tags: swagger, pact

We are trying to implement CDCT in our project. But our team is not ready to implement separate test class to generate pact consumer contract file, but they do have already implemented and generating the swagger file.

***Is there a way to convert swagger file into pact consumer contract file? ***

Highly appreciate if any solution for the same.

We tried couple of solutions from ChatGPT, but those solution are not serve the purpose.

Comment: the answer is on the pact documentation: https://docs.pact.io/faq#can-i-generate-my-pact-file-from-something-like-swagger